# Codeigniter displaying total added likes from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using MVC in codeigniter and I have a MySql table that has pages made by users **page_id** and topics **topic_number** as shown in the image below (Table page). pages can have multiple **topic numbers**.

I also have another table called **table page likes** (shown in the image below also). This table also has **page_id** and **topic_number** but it has two more fields, which are, **like** and **user_who_liked_topic_number**.

[image]

My problem is that, I would like to display all the topic numbers that have or dont have likes. But if I only fetch topic numbers from the **Table_page_likes**, I will not get topic_numbers that dont have any likes recorded. which is why I am using both tables.

The first table is fetched from the database where all the Topic_number is printed out. Then each Topic_number is searched in the **table_pages_like** to find if it has any like records and display it next to the Page_id and topic_number.

This is my code so far, but I am not sure how to do the second step, which is to fetch each page_id with any number of likes from the table **table_page_likes**

**controller_page.php**

```
     function viewdata() {
    $data['pages'] = $this->model_page->get_pages();

    $this->load->view('view_page', $data);


}


function get_like($post_id, $topic_number) {

    $data['liked_pages'] = $this->model_page->get_likes_model($post_id, topic_number);

    $this->load->view('view_page', $data);


}
```

**model_page.php**

```
       function get_pages() {

    $query = $this->db->get_where('table_pages');
    return $query->result_array();

}

 function get_likes($page_id, $topic_number) {

        $query = $this->db->get_where('table_pages_likes', array('page_id' => $page_id , 'topic_number' => $topic_number));

}
```

**view_page.php**

```
              <?php foreach($pages as $value): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['page_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['topic_number']; ?></td>

                <?php foreach($liked_pages as $value): ?>
                    <td><?php echo $value['page_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['topic_number']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['like']; ?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your model method to something like below instead of creating and calling two methods for displaying likes:

```
class model_page extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_page_likes() {
        $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT p.id, p.tid, IF(SUM(pl.like) > 0, SUM(pl.like), 0) AS likes FROM pages AS p LEFT JOIN page_likes pl ON p.id = pl.pid AND p.tid = pl.tid GROUP BY p.tid, p.id HAVING likes >= 0 ORDER BY p.id, p.tid");
        return $qry->result_array();
    }
}
```

Above query considers that you have the following tables similar to below (no indexes identified here yet):

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `page_likes` (
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `like` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And have the following sample data:

```
pages:
    id     tid  
------  --------
    11         1
    11         2
    11         3
    12         1
    12         2

page_likes
   pid     tid    like  
------  ------  --------
    11       1         1
    11       1         1
    11       1         1
    12       2         1
```

The above query will give you results like:

```
id     tid  likes   
------  ------  --------
    11       1  3       
    11       2  0       
    11       3  0       
    12       1  0       
    12       2  1
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
- edited method above.

On your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['pages'] = $this->model_page->get_page_likes();
    $this->load->view('view_page', $data);
}
```

On your view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Page ID</th>
        <th>Topic ID</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($pages as $value): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['tid']; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($value['likes']) echo $value['likes']; else echo 'no likes to show'; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Harvey thats very cleaver. I am trying to test it, but my view isnt working becuase I am not sure how to display it according to the new model set up

Comment: Try the following:
  
On your file named "controller_page.php":

function viewdata() {
 $data['pages'] = $this->mode_page->get_page_likes();
 $this->load->view('view_page', $data;)
}

On your file named "view_page.php":
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Page ID</th>
   <th>Topic ID</th>
   <th>Likes</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($pages as $value): ?>
    <tr>
   <td><?php echo $value['pid']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $value['tid']; ?></td>
   <td><?php if ($value['likes']) echo $value['likes']; else echo 'no likes to show'; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>

Comment: Thanks Harvey, but I am getting an error saying "Cannot use object of type mysqli as array" because of the  "<td><?php echo $value['pid']; ?></td> " on the views page. I tried a different table but still getting the same error. any ideas mate?

Comment: Try `$value->pid` instead. I don't have a CodeIgniter install at the moment to test this, but just play around with it. The errors are your clue, like, "cannot use object of type as array" suggests that you are trying to use a variable as an array instead of an object.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried it all and I hate to be a pain, but its not working Harvey. $value->pid gives an "Undefined property: mysqli::$pid" error. Do you possibly think its my table structure?

Comment: I've upvoted you and I'm giving you a tick aswell, can you please let me know how to display it in the view? I've tried evertying thanks

Comment: I edited my answer above. The reason it wasn't working before was we returned the query object instead of the result as an array. On the view, I wrongly used a variable, as it wasn't `$value['pid']` but `$value['id']`.